# Переделать код написанный с помощью If в код с оператором Switch/тернарный

Tags: c#, winforms

Задание: Составьте программу, позволяющую совершать покупки в виртуальном магазине. 

Пользователь может выбирать товар (checkBox) и вводить количество (textbox), в лейблах указаны цены.

 
В последнем label ему выводится посчитанная сумма.

Сделать всё нужно с помощью оператора switch или тернарного оператора.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((checkBox2.Checked) && (checkBox3.Checked) && (checkBox1.Checked))
    {
        label2.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) *
        Convert.ToInt32(label3.Text)) + (Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) *
        Convert.ToInt32(label4.Text)) + (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) *
        Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text))).ToString();
    }
    else if ((checkBox1.Checked) && (checkBox2.Checked))
    {
        label2.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) *
        Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text)) + (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) *
        Convert.ToInt32(label3.Text))).ToString();
    }
    else if ((checkBox1.Checked) && (checkBox3.Checked))
    {
        label2.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * 
        Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text)) + (Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) * 
        Convert.ToInt32(label4.Text))).ToString();
    }
    else if ((checkBox2.Checked) && (checkBox3.Checked))
    {
        label2.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) * 
        Convert.ToInt32(label3.Text)) + (Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) * 
        Convert.ToInt32(label4.Text))).ToString();
    }
    else if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        label2.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * 
        Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text)).ToString();
    }
    else if (checkBox2.Checked)
    {
        label2.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) * 
        Convert.ToInt32(label3.Text)).ToString();
    }
    else if (checkBox3.Checked)
    {
        label2.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) * 
        Convert.ToInt32(label4.Text)).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Что у вас не получается? Представьте `checkBox*.Checked` в виде соответствующих битов в числе. Тогда конструкцию можно будет легко переделать под Switch.

Comment: С оператором switch столкнулась первый раз, не особо понимаю его конструкцию.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос описание, что именно делает приведенный фрагмент кода и какое поведение ожидается, если он ведет себя некорректно. Для редактирования вопроса под ним есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1036608/edit). Вероятно есть не только вариант через switch, но и более короткий и понятный вариант.

Comment: @Kirai https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

Comment: Используете, судя по коду, WinForms?

Comment: @rdorn именно так

Comment: Было уже похожее задание [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1030530/222542). Там конечно нет никаких  10-ти этажных `switch` или `if`. Мне лично странно, вас совсем не учат ООП? Работать через создание собственных классов? Почему вы пишите на `C#` как будто бы на `C` в процедурном стиле?

Comment: @Bulson по ссылке ответ хорош (+1), но тут, судя по коду, базовая алгоритмика хромает на обе ноги. Попробую аккуратно ответить так, чтобы решение было найдено самостоятельно, так сказать направить в нужную сторону. Все таки биндинги с нуля не всем по зубам, хотя я их тоже очень люблю.

Comment: @rdorn, я подумаю, может сейчас чего-нибудь напишу попроще...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте разбираться, для чего у вас такой много-этажный `if`? Фактически вы проверяете все возможные сочетания из трех бит, которые в вашем случае представлены `CheckBox`-ами. Для трех бит получилось 7 полезных вариантов + 1 бесполезный (все галки сняты), итого 8 вариантов. Что будет если мы добавим еще один `CheckBox`? Количество вариантов для обработки удвоится, а если товаров будет 100? Я боюсь представить себе число `2^100`, но более печально то, что в этом случае ваш алгоритм не сможет выполниться за сколь-нибудь адекватное время если и дальше следовать использованной у вас логике. Попробуйте написать простой цикл от `0` до `long.MaxValue`, в котором будет просто выводиться текущее значение счетчика, и посмотрите на время его выполнения, а это только `2^63`...

Будем исправлять. Для начала вспоминаем, что цепочку последовательных вычислений вовсе не обязательно писать одной строкой, а можно разбить на последовательность простых вычислений, результаты которых передавать по цепочке через локальную переменную. Простой пример:

```
x  = 2 + 3 + 4 + 5;
   |
   V
a = 2 + 3;
a = a + 4;
a = a + 5;
x = a;
```

Теперь, если применить такой подход к вашему коду, мы легко уменьшим количество `if` с ужасного `2^N` до `N`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int result = 0;
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        result = result  + (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text));
    }
    if (checkBox2.Checked)
    {
        result = result  + (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(label3.Text));
    }
    if (checkBox3.Checked)
    {
        result = result + (Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(label4.Text));
    }
    label2.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Как видите, даже `else` в данном случае не требуется, каждое из трех значений обрабатывается независимо от остальных, а результат такой же, как в исходном варианте.

Идем дальше. Теперь немного поиграем с синтаксическими конструкциями, которые есть в языке, для сокращения объема текста полученного фрагмента кода.

1. Для начала `(a = a + b) == (a += b)`:

   ```
   result = result  + (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text));
   // заменим на:
   result += (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text));
   ```
2. Тернарный оператор позволяет обойтись без явного `if` при вычислении выражений. но нужно понимать, что ни какой магии нет, это все тот же `if`, но "замаскированный" для удобного использования в выражениях:

   ```
   if (checkBox1.Checked)
   {
       result += (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text));
   }
   else
   {
       result += 0;
   }
   //можно заменить на
   result += checkBox1.Checked //проверяемое условие
             ? (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text))//если истина
             : 0;                                                             //если ложь
   ```

Ну вот, теперь у вас есть все кусочки головоломки, осталось только собрать все воедино, но это вы должны сделать самостоятельно, если хотите научиться, а не просто "скопировать-сдать-забыть".

Следующим шагом подумайте, как можно применить циклы и массивы, чтобы иметь возможность обрабатывать любое количество элементов, без необходимости явно писать код для каждого отдельного элемента.

---

К слову: не знаю как автор задания предполагал использовать тут `switch`, но единственный вариант, который приходит в голову в попытке таки "натянуть сову на глобус" в результате даст все те же `2^N` вариантов, что, в целом, ни разу не лучше исходного варианта с "этажеркой" из `if`.

Comment: Отлично. Все последовательно, подробно и понятно.